# Built an sbt assembly, then running with sbt 'run-main <class>' fails with [error] Not a valid command: run-main

Tags: sbt

That issue shows up elsewhere and people suggest using runMain, but that ends up with ClassNotFoundException, whereas this trace is what I get:

```
sbt:reach-exe> run-main org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: run-main
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: run-main (similar: runMain, bgRunMain, fgRunMain)
[error] run-main org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer
[error]         ^
```

This has been a difficult query for good googlefoo. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's `runMain` in newer versions of sbt. Dash-separated names were deprecated some time ago.

If there is only one `main` you can just use `run` command.

Comment: This command: sbt 'runMain org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer' ends with [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.clulab.processors.server.ProcessorServer -- That's what makes this so confusing.

Comment: runMain also complained with [warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list

Comment: I do not have an answer to my own question, but I have learned that I don't need to build a fat jar; the program runs with the usual 'run-main' command without building.

Comment: @Mateusz, It helped me. Thanks.